# Laptop gets very slow while copying/moving files

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, laptop, toshiba-laptop

My laptop used to work great in every aspect on Windows 10 days ago. Two days ago I installed Linux Mint to give it a try and formatted the hard disk, but I couldn't acclimatise to the Linux OS.

So I downloaded a Windows 10 iso and did a fresh install. I have since discovered that my laptop becomes quite slow while transferring files! I can't even access the settings or open a browser while the transferring processes.

The laptop is a Toshiba C55-B.

Comment: Have you installed drivers? What laptop model is that?

Comment: Run a chkdsk on the C drive

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, all drivers are installed, It's Toshiba C55-B

Comment: @Moab "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems"

Comment: Where did you get the Win10 ISO file from? Have you done a sweep for viruses?

Comment: @Burgi from microsoft download center...and yes

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know how you transfer files, to local partition or to USB drive or to Network drive. It depends on.

Please make sure to install all storage driver or connection driver like SATA or motherboard from manufacturer's website to make sure all are work on Windows 10.

We can also check by using process explorer to see if there is any high CPU or memory usage with certain process during this process.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2012/11/23/wpt-wprxperf-capture-high-cpu-disk-io-file-registry-networking-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-paged-poolnonpaged-pool-andor-application-slowness/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2011/05/17/4-must-have-windows-high-cpu-troubleshooting-tools/

Comment: The problem occurs during transfer to local or to USB drive! from task manager i noticed the disk process jumps to 100% while transferring.